# cannot install xmonad-extras?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Havenot the software in hackage tested thoroughly ? `cabal install xmonad-eval` even causes the following error:

```
$cabal install xmonad-extras
...    
[10 of 22] Compiling Hint.Reflection  ( src/Hint/Reflection.hs, dist/build/Hint/Reflection.o)
src/Hint/Reflection.hs:75:41:
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `a0 -> String'
Expected type: Id 
Actual type: a0 -> String
In the return type of a call of `getUnqualName'
In the first argument of `Class', namely `(getUnqualName c)'
Failed to install hint-0.3.3.5
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hint-0.3.3.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
xmonad-extras-0.10.1.2 depends on hint-0.3.3.5 which failed to install.
```

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Comment: One upload, almost four years ago:Sun Feb 22 15:11:28 UTC 2009. Looks like an abandoned package. Early 2009 was ghc-6.10 or so. You _might_ be able to get it working by `cabal unpack`ing it and editing the `.cabal` and the sources until it builds.

Comment: such a package should be removed from hackage ?

Comment: Nope. It's good to have an archive of the code. Existence on hackage is no guarantee in itself of quality or lack of bitrot.

Comment: ok, how about xmonad-extras ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By upgrading GHC from 7.0.3 to 7.4.1, it works great .